# Отлов печати Windows

Tags: print, hook, c, печать, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить содержимое документа, отправленного на печать? Сам отлов происходит с помощью `FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification` и `GetPrinterJobs`. Получилось доже достать файлы `.spl`. Можно ли их конвертировать, или перехватить еще момент копирования файлов в спулер с помощью хуков, или инжектироваться в приложения? Пробовал все варианты, даже библиотеку `madchook.dll`.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: redmon не подойдёт? http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но надо именно свое написать, а не использовать стороннее ПО. Чужие библиотеки - пожалуйста, но не программы. Есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: @mozg207 Если это учебное задание, то, возможно, имеет смысл заглянуть в исходники этого RedMon'а.

Comment: Это не учебное задание, и я только сейчас заметил dll) Прошу прощения за невнимательность. Если я сумею с ней разобраться, то это очень хороший вариант. Спасибо большое. Но я все еще открыт для других вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае *.spl* файл представляет из себя [EMF-файл](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile), то есть содержит последовательность аппаратно-независимых функций *GDI*. Вот [здесь](http://www.undocprint.org/formats/winspool/emf) есть информация о структуре этих файлов и есть ссылки на библиотеки для работы с ними. Я использовал только первую (на VB.Net) - она в большинстве случаев работает нормально. На C там тоже что-то есть, но эти проекты я не смотрел.

В любом случае, если по этой ссылке вы не найдете подходящую библиотеку, вам надо искать что-то для чтения EMF-файлов.

Дополнительно обратите внимание вот на что:

- .spl-файл не всегда содержит *EMF*. В некоторых случаях там могут быть сырые данные, в формате принтера, на который выводится документ (*RAW*). Например, это может быть в такой ситуации: вы печатаете документ с Windows-машины на принтер, подключенный к машине с Linux, то есть в роли принтсервера выступает Linux-машина. В этом случае спулер вашей Windows-машины не может послать на принтсервер *EMF*, потому что это специфичный для Windows формат и Linux о нем ничего не знает. Поэтому спулер с помощью драйвера принтера сразу перегоняет документ в *RAW* и сохраняет в очереди печати уже *RAW*.
- начиная с Windows Vista в Windows появился [новый способ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563787(v=vs.85).aspx) печати документов  с помощью [XPS print API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ff686814(v=vs.85).aspx). Насчет этого способа я точно не знаю, но скорее всего, когда печать будет выполняться этим способом .spl-файл будет содержать xps. Имейте это в виду.